# Replace String In a File

Tags: linux, awk, sed, replace

I have a file as following

```
ID,SEQ,PO_NUM,BATCH,CREATE_DT
99001100788259,127856626,111,20230801
99001100788270,223412976,111,20230801
99001100788281,112120972,222,20230801
```

I want to replace the first two columns last 4 digits by adding 1 digit to each number as following:

```
99001100789360,127857737,111,20230801
99001100789381,223413087,111,20230801
99001100789392,112121083,222,20230801
```

0 should become 1
1 should become 2
2 should become 3
3 should become 4
4 should become 5
5 should become 6
6 should become 7
7 should become 8
8 should become 9
9 should become 0

I tried sed but not able to figure out the last 4 digits logic.

Comment: Since sed doesn't have arithmetic operations and you want to add 1 digit to each number, it wouldn't be a good choice of tool for this.

Comment: Can either field ever have less than 4 digits? If so, please include such a case in your sample input/output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one potential solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    FS = ","
}

NR == 1 {
    print
}

NR > 1 {
    a = split($1, b, "")
    c = split($2, d, "")
    e = split($0, f, "")
    for (i = 1; i <= e; i++) {
        if (i > a - 4 && i <= a) {
            printf "%s", (f[i] + 1 == 10 ? "0" : f[i] + 1)
        } else if (i > a + c - 3 && i <= a + c + 1) {
            printf "%s", (f[i] + 1 == 10 ? "0" : f[i] + 1)
        } else {
            printf "%s%s", f[i], (i == e ? "\n" : "")
        }
    }
}' file.txt
ID,SEQ,PO_NUM,BATCH,CREATE_DT
99001100789360,127857737,111,20230801
99001100789381,223413087,111,20230801
99001100789392,112121083,222,20230801
```

Comment: `split($1, b, "")`, etc. will do different things in different awks since splitting on null is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Would you please try the following:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '
    NR>1 {                                                      # skip header line
        for (i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {                              # loop over 1st and 2nd fields
            str = substr($i, 1, length($i) - 4)                 # drop rightmost 4 digits
            for (j = length($i) - 3; j <= length($i); j++) {    # loop over rightmost 4 digits
                str = str (substr($i, j, 1) + 1) % 10           # add 1 to the digit, take the modulo of 10, and append to the left string
            }
            $i = str                                            # update the i-th field
        }
    }
1' input_file
```

Output:

```
ID,SEQ,PO_NUM,BATCH,CREATE_DT
99001100789360,127857737,111,20230801
99001100789381,223413087,111,20230801
99001100789392,112121083,222,20230801
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/....,/\n&\n/
        h
        y/0123456789/1234567890/
        G
        s/.*\n(.*)\n.*\n(.*)\n.*\n/\2\1/' file
```

Delimit the last four digits of the first column by newlines.

Make a copy of the current line in the hold space.

Translate each digit as required.

Append the copy to the amended line.

Use substitution to replace the last four digits of the first column by the amended version.

N.B. No arithmetic is involved only translation and substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input is `/tmp/x.csv` then do this:

```
awk -F, -vOFS=, 'NR==1;NR>1{$1++;$2++;print}' /tmp/x.csv
ID,SEQ,PO_NUM,BATCH,CREATE_DT
99001100788260,127856627,111,20230801
99001100788271,223412977,111,20230801
99001100788282,112120973,222,20230801
```

What this does is set the input and output field separator to `,` (`-F, -vOFS=,`). Then, if it's the first line (`NR==1;`) just print the line as is, otherwise (`NR>1`) add 1 to the first field (`$1++`) and second field (`$2++`) then print the entire line (`print`).

Comment: The OP isn't looking to add 1 to each field but instead independently add 1 to each of the last 4 digits in each field. Compare the output you get to the output they want.

Comment: Oh.  Well, then change `$1++` to `$1+=1111`.

Comment: That wouldn't add 1 to each of the last 4 digits of the number, it'd add 1111 to the whole number. If you were to add 1 to each of the last 2 digits of 789, per the OPs example, the result would be 790 which is not the same as adding 11 to 789 which would result in 800.

Comment: Yeah, I know math. I just got tired of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU AWK

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '
    NR>1 {
        for(col=1; col<=2; col++){
            n=split($col,a,"");
            for(i=n; i>=n-4; i--)
                a[i]=substr(a[i]+1, length(a[i]+1), 1)
            for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
                result = result a[i]
            $col = result
            result = ""
        }
    }1 
' file

99001100799360,127867737,111,20230801
99001100799381,223423087,111,20230801
99001100799392,112131083,222,20230801
```